# Como trocar informações em modo full-duplex?

Tags: c, socket

Observe os dois códigos abaixo:

Cliente.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define SRV_ADDR "127.0.0.1"
#define SRV_PORT "9009"

int make_socket(void){

    int ecode, sockfd;

    struct addrinfo *results=NULL, hints;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));

    hints.ai_family=AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol=IPPROTO_TCP;

    if((ecode=getaddrinfo(SRV_ADDR, SRV_PORT, &hints, &results))!=0){

        sockfd=-1;

    }else{

        struct addrinfo *it=NULL;

        for(it=results; it!=NULL; it=it->ai_next){

            if((sockfd=socket(it->ai_family, it->ai_socktype, it->ai_protocol))==-1){

                continue;
            }

            if(connect(sockfd, it->ai_addr, it->ai_addrlen)==0){

                break;
            }

            close(sockfd);
        }

        freeaddrinfo(results);

        if(it==NULL){

            sockfd=-1;
        }
    }

    return sockfd;
}

short get_msg(char *msg, size_t n){

    int rv;

    if(fgets(msg, n, stdin)!=NULL){

        size_t len=strlen(msg);

        msg[len-1]='\0'; //elimina o \n

        rv=0;

    }else{

        rv=-1;
    }

    return rv;
}

int main(void){

    int sockfd=make_socket();

    if(sockfd!=-1){

        short rv;
        char msg[101];

        printf("\n");

        do{

            do{

                printf("Você >");

                if((rv=get_msg(msg, 101))!=0){

                    printf("\n* Falha na leitura!");
                    printf("\n  |.__Escreva a mensagem novamente.\n\n");
                }

                send(sockfd, msg, 101, 0);

            }while(rv!=0);

            if(strcmp(msg, "!exit")!=0){

                recv(sockfd, msg, 101, 0);

                printf("Estranho: %s\n", msg);
            }

        }while(strcmp(msg, "!exit")!=0);

        close(sockfd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Servidor.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int make_socket(void){

    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo *results=NULL, hints;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));

    hints.ai_flags=AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_family=AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol=IPPROTO_TCP;

    if(getaddrinfo(NULL, "9009", &hints, &results)!=0){

         sockfd=-1;

    }else{

          struct addrinfo *it=NULL;

          for(it=results; it!=NULL; it=it->ai_next){

              if((sockfd=socket(it->ai_family, it->ai_socktype, it->ai_protocol))==-1){

                  continue;
              }

              if(bind(sockfd, it->ai_addr, it->ai_addrlen)==0){

                  break;
              }

              close(sockfd);
          }

          freeaddrinfo(results);

          if(it==NULL){

              sockfd=-1;

          }else{

              if(listen(sockfd, 1)==-1){

                  sockfd=-1;
              }
          }
    }

    return sockfd;
}

short get_msg(char *msg, size_t n){

    int rv;

    if(fgets(msg, n, stdin)!=NULL){

        size_t len=strlen(msg);

        msg[len-1]='\0'; //elimina o \n

        rv=0;

    }else{

        rv=-1;
    }

    return rv;
}

int main(void){

    int sockfd, csockfd;

    if((sockfd=make_socket())!=-1){

        if((csockfd=accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL))!=-1){

            short rv;
            char msg[101];

            printf("\n");

            do{

                recv(csockfd, msg, 101, 0);

                printf("Estranho: %s\n", msg);

                if(strcmp(msg, "!exit")!=0){

                    do{

                        printf("Você >");

                        if((rv=get_msg(msg, 101))!=0){

                            printf("\n* Falha na leitura!");
                            printf("\n  |.__Escreva a mensagem novamente.\n\n");
                        }

                        send(csockfd, msg, 101, 0);

                    }while(rv!=0);
                }

            }while(strcmp(msg, "!exit")!=0);

            close(csockfd);
        }

        close(sockfd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Agora observe a execução de ambos:

Cliente:

```
t-002@localhost:~/Documents/C$ gcc -Wall client.c -o client
t-002@localhost:~/Documents/C$ ./client

Você >Olá 
Estranho: Não posso conversar agora :(
Você >Okay amigo :(
Estranho: !exit
```

Servidor:

```
t-002@localhost:~/Documents/C$ gcc -Wall server.c -o server
t-002@localhost:~/Documents/C$ ./server

Estranho: Olá
Você >Não posso conversar agora :(
Estranho: Okay amigo :(
Você >!exit
```

Notou que a comunicação entre o servidor e o cliente foi feita em sentido duplo, porém não de forma simutânea? Pois bem, essa forma de troca de dados se chama *half-duplex*. Um exemplo mais prático disso são os *walkie-talkies*:

[image: walkie-talkies]

Aqui observa-se o seguinte: Enquanto um dos *walkie-talkies* fala o outro só poderá ouvir, ou seja, a transmissão de dados ocorre em função do tempo. É quase a mesma coisa que o meu servidor e cliente lá em cima, porém lá foi pré-estabelecido quem falava primeiro e ainda por cima era necessário esperar o outro responder para poder falar de volta.

**Portanto**, venho com a seguinte dúvida: É possível estabelecer uma conexão entre um cliente e um servidor escritos/programados em C onde os dados são trocados de forma dupla ou bidirecional simutânea, ou seja, em modo *full-duplex*?

Comment: De uma olhada nesse projeto [https://github.com/.../full-duplex-chat-tcp-ip](https://github.com/apsrcreatix/Socket-Programming-With-C/tree/master/07-full-duplex-chat-tcp-ip) acredito que atenda sua especificação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isso é criar duas threads (ou dois processos filhos no Unix/Linux), sendo que uma thread faz recepção e outra faz envio.

Pseudo-código de 1 servidor que trata apenas 1 conexão e depois finaliza, mas faz send e receive "simultâneos":

```
1. cria socket  
2. faz bind
3. faz listen
4. faz accept
5. cria thread de recepção
6. cria thread de envio
7. fica parado na thread principal (por exemplo, faz um getchar)
```

Tanto a thread de recepção quanto a thread de envio utiliza o mesmo socket retornado pela função accept.

Thread de recepção:

```
1. faz receive
2. se retornou erro ou fim de conexão, finaliza programa (chama exit)
3. não foi erro nem fim da conexão, então processa dados recebidos
4. volta para 1
```

Thread de envio:

```
1. gera dados a serem enviados
2. faz send
3. se retornou erro, então finaliza programa (chama exit)
4. volta para 1
```

Uma outra maneira, e provavelmente a mais comum, de fazer isso é utilizando programação por eventos.

Neste caso, utiliza-se uma função da pilha TCP chamada select (que na prática hoje é obsoleta), ou uma função do s.o. (epoll no Linux, ou GetQueuedCompletionStatus no Windows) para verificar se existe algum evento pendente no socket da conexão.

Este "evento" pode ser relacionado a recepção ou a envio.

No Linux um evento de recepção significa que pode ser feita uma recepção no socket em questão, que pode (mas não é garantido) ter dados prontos para serem recebidos. E um evento de envio significa que pode (mas também não é garantido) ser feito um send no socket em questão. Como não existe garantia de que pode ser tentada uma operação de envio ou recepção, utiliza-se o socket em modo "não-blocante", assim na recepção ou no envio o programa não fica bloqueado para esperar que a operação seja efetuada.

No Linux o funcionamento é "reativo". Isto é, o programa pergunta para o s.o. (através do select ou epoll) se pode fazer uma operação de recepção ou envio, e quando recebe um evento do s.o. então o programa tenta efetuar a operação.

No Windows, ao contrário, o funcionamento é "proativo". O programa cria a conexão preparada para trabalhar com IOCP, e depois, efetua as operações. O programa não fica parado esperando a operação terminar. O programa sabe que a operação terminou quando recebe um evento através da função GetQueuedCompletionStatus referente à operação que foi iniciada anteriormente.

Na prática, tanto no Linux quanto no Windows a programação por eventos é feita usando threads, tendo uma thread ou mais reservadas para tratamento dos eventos recebidos através do epoll ou GetQueuedCompletionStatus.

Neste [link](https://suchprogramming.com/epoll-in-3-easy-steps/) (achado no Google) encontra-se um exemplo simples de uso de epoll sem threads adicionais em Linux, e neste outro [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/95363/Another-TCP-echo-server-using-IOCP) uma receita e um exemplo passo a passo de um server (também não usando threads adicionais) com IOCP em Windows.